# How to add "-lespeak" to codeblocks?

Tags: linux, linker, codeblocks, espeak

I use Ubuntu 16.04 and it's `gedit` editor to codding. I can compile my programs with espeak library used within, by adding `-lespeak` at the end of compile command like this on Linux terminal:
`g++ -o myapp myapp.cpp -lespeak` , But I don't know how should I add what files to codeblocks for `espeak`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Navigate: Workspace -> Your-Project -> **Build options** -> **Linker settings** -> **Other linker options**. Add `-lespeak`. OK out. Build

Comment: I wrote `espeak` in that place you said, it worked. thanks!